# Full speech in Finding Forrester

Tags: plot-explanation, finding-forrester

In one of the last scenes of the movie Finding Forrester, an essay is read by Sean Connery's character.  A few lines in, music overtakes and you can't hear the rest of the speech.  **Is there a full version of the script available that shows the speech in its entirety?**

Speech scene:

In the final scene of the movie, a letter is read which possibly mentions part of the drawn out speech (though it may refer to something else entirely, it wasn't made clear):

> [...] someone I once knew wrote that we walk away from our dreams, afraid that we may fail.  Or worse yet... afraid we may succeed

Comment: Question 3, it makes me think of the widely spread Marianne Williamson quote: "Our deepest fear is not that we are inadequate. Our deepest fear is that we are powerful beyond measure. It is our light, not our darkness that most frightens us." Apparently others have this same thought, even though it seems paradoxical.

Comment: This is at least two different questions (possibly three, depending on the answer to #2); you should ask them separately since they will have different answers.

Comment: Mike is right, at least the first question should be separated from the other two. I'm voting to close it as two broad.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more specified.